# Joomla/PHP how to add <meta property> instead of a <meta name> tags to the the header?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

Dear Joomla community,

I'm working on a little system plugin to inject Facebook Open Graph properties into an article. Therefore I've been using `$document->setMetaData()`. But now I discovered that this adds `<meta name="">` tags to the header of the page, but Facebook expects `<meta property="">` tags.

What's the easiest way to put a `<meta property="">` tag into the page header?

Please explain in as much detail as possible, as I'm absolutely new to Joomla plugin developemnt.

Any advice is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Starting from Joomla 3.6 you can add 'property' attribute using setMetaData

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData('og:image', 'https://cdn.joomla.org/images/Joomla_logo.png', 'property');
```

Reference : https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/10682

Answer (score 6):

Never mind, I just discovered the mighty `$document->addCustomTag()` API call. 
Thanks you anyway!

Comment: Yes, this is convenient for adding Open Graph tags.